# How to get natural size of an image referenced in <input type="image" ... > in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, input

I have an `input` of type `"image"` on my web page. I want to get dimensions of that original image (not the DOM element). How to do it in javascript?

The only solution I know is to get value of the `src` attribute, load image manually and get its size as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626505/261217). But I know image is already loaded, since it is displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have no additional styles on that `<input type="image"`, you may use `clientWidth/clientHeight` the same as for `img` tag (by default, button will have the same width/height as src image). Unfortunately none of browsers support `naturalWidth/naturalHeight` for input of type image. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ktUA/4/)

At the same time - I see no big problem with using additional img element to get width/height of an image. In most cases image will be taken from cache.

Comment: And what about creating `Image` dynamically in JS? Will it be taken from cache in this case?

Comment: Frankly speaking I thought we are talking about dynamically created `Image` ). In general - there is no difference. Once it is loaded to client, it will be taken from cache next time it is needed. No matter how it is added on a page. CSS sprites are based on this. Of course, it depends on caching settings, but usually it will work fine.